# Font awesome icons misaligned on converting into directives

Tags: css, angularjs-directive

Icons are misaligned if I use directive and working fine if I used plain html code..

Method 1) font awesome icons using directives (icons are horizontally misaligned):

js:

```
app.directive("roIcon", function() {
   return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "templates/roIcon.html",
       scope: {
           type: "@"
       }
   };
});
```

"roIcon.html" template:

```
<span ng-if="type === 'add'">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg stacked-icons"  ng-if="type === 'export-file'">
     <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <span class="fa-stack stack-bg">
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-small fa-stack-1x"></i>
     </span>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg stacked-fork" ng-hide="isTile == true" ng-if="type === 'start-workflow'">
     <i class="fa fa-code-fork fa-rotate-90 fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <span class="fa-stack stack-bg">
         <i class="fa fa-plus fa-small fa-stack-1x"></i>
     </span>
</span>
```

Icons directive included in html:

```
<ro-icon type="add"></ro-icon>
<ro-icon type="export-file"></ro-icon>
<ro-icon type="start-workflow"></ro-icon>
```

Method 2) Direct inclusion of icons into html file is working fine:

```
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg stacked-icons" title="export file">
     <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <span class="fa-stack stack-bg">
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-small fa-stack-1x"></i>
     </span>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg stacked-fork">
     <i class="fa fa-code-fork fa-rotate-90 fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <span class="fa-stack stack-bg">
         <i class="fa fa-plus fa-small fa-stack-1x"></i>
     </span>
</span>
```

The only difference I can see in both the view source is the icons rendered with directives contains a wrapper non-html tag ...., the rest of the html is same.
I am not able to find out whether this non-html  tag is making any difference in alignment as shown in figure?
Appreciate your help..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell us here. Hard to 'see' without any live example. However, I took the code you've provided and put it into this plunkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/JdeRQJ5kAIJnfAgl14v1?p=preview) running angular 1.3.11 with FontAwesome 4.1.0.

To me, all icons looks perfectly aligned although I'm not sure as to what you are after. Make sure none of your own custom css aren't interfering with FontAwesome.for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and plunkr example.